# Where and how do I register an object for receiving a Notification?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications

For example, when memory gets low, the System sends a `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification. That's all Apple says in its docs at that point. But where does this notification come from, and to which method is it sent? Or where and how do I register what that I get notified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sent to the notification center, where all notifications are centralized. An object that wants to get informed about this notification registers itself to the notification center by telling which notification it wants to get informed and which method should be invoqued when the notification is raised.

For more information you can take a look to [Notification programming topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) and [NSNotification class reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .

Answer (score 18):

From within the initialization code of the class you wish to receive the notification make the following method call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleMemoryWarning:) name: UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
```

This assumes that your class also implements a handleMemoryWarning method as follows:

```
- (void) handleMemoryWarning:(NSNotification *)notification
{
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call removeObserver in that class's dealloc.

Comment: Can't edit.  Selector should be @selector(handleMemoryWarning:)

Comment: Not necessary to remove observer if you target iOS 9 and up:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

Much simpler to use the application delegate and implement the optional method

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
```

Most common notifications are also available translated into calls to a delegate, typically to optional methods in a formal protocol.  Your delegate can be whatever object you like.

Comment: Note how you get the delegate name by taking the name of the notification and removing the `UI` from the beginning, `Notification` from the end and downcasing the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that your selector will need to take the notification as an argument.

If you use something like @selector(handleMemoryWarning) and - (void) handleMemoryWarning { } the object WILL NOT send the notification and you'll still be holding onto all of your memory.

I was just bitten by this.

Comment: Totally not true (and I just tried it, too). You can use the selector with no params or with params. Also use "hardware -> simulate memory warning" in the iOS simulator.

Comment: Really? Did you test that across all devices and OS versions? I witnessed this happening firsthand in my code when testing.

Comment: Hi Ben, I don't doubt that you saw it on some device and OS version. That said, I've NEVER seen `performSelector` care about a param or not. Any idea what device and OS version it was?

Comment: You can choose whether you want a method with a parameter or without by using @selector(foo) or @selector(foo:). So if you use the former form then, as Ben warns, you will need to pass a param.

Comment: Yar: don't recall the specific device and OS version, and I was as surprised at the time as you are reading this.